# Upper Left Corner of Android Action Bar Widget

Tags: android

Can I ask what is the name of the feature of the Android action bar at the upper left hand corner which allows the user to press it and see a droplist? Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's called a navigation drawer.

Comment: See here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I totally missed that out!